# Does ternary operator can only do one kind of condition?

Tags: ternary

ternary make code concise and readable, I'm curious about how to change the following `if condition` to ternary operator:

`var1 = if(true){'a'}`;

I try the following

`var1 =  true? 'a': ;`

since it require nothing to do with `false` condition, I leave blank after `:`, but apparently it gives me a error.

Is there a way to do this?

--------update---------

The intention of using the above example is that I want to simplify the problem, however it made everyone more confuse, so I post my original code:

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){ $sub_count = 0; }`

`$sub_count = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'? 0 : ;`

how to change the if condition to ternary ?

Comment: Yes, `var1 = 'a'`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Try to answer the following question for `var1 = condition ? 'foo' : ;` - what will be the value of `var1` if `condition` is false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sub_count = null;
$sub_count = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'? 0 : null;

// To check:
if(!isset($sub_count))
{
   // Do something because $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'GET'
} else {
    if($sub_count===0)
    {
        // REQUEST METHOD IS GET
    }
}
```